# Can I use `JWTStatelessUserAuthentication` instead of `JWTAuthentication` in my Django project, even without multiple applications?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm currently working on a Django project, and I'm exploring the use of authentication mechanisms provided by Simple-JWT. In the documentation, I noticed the option of using `JWTStatelessUserAuthentication` for single sign-on (SSO) between separate Django apps that share the same token secret key.

My project doesn't involve multiple applications, but I'm intrigued by the potential benefits of `JWTStatelessUserAuthentication`, especially in avoiding database queries for user info in each API call, which seems to be a characteristic of `JWTAuthentication`.

I'd appreciate any insights, experiences, or recommendations regarding the use of these authentication methods in a Django project. Thanks!

**Specific Questions:**

1. Is it advisable to use `JWTStatelessUserAuthentication` in a project without multiple applications?
2. Are there any specific considerations or limitations associated with using `JWTStatelessUserAuthentication` in a project context like mine?